# How exactly does a drugstore robbery work?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I am a little bit confused about the robbery of a drug store in GTA Online. So I have some questions:

- After the robbery, I sometimes get a 2-star wanted level, and other times a 3-star wanted level. Why does this happen?
- Is it harder to lose the cops after a robbery? I have a lot of problems after a robbery to lose them.
- Sometimes, when I drive by a drug store which I already robbed, I automatically get a wanted star. Why?
- Do you have some other usefull hints for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- When you kill the cashier, you'll get a 3* wanted level. If you just threaten him, you'll get only 2*
- No it isn't! It's always the same strength of the police at the different levels.
- This is because they know your face or you drive with a stolen car. If you drive with a stolen car, this "random" star can appear everywhere.

**Tips**

- Don't shoot the cashier. Just shoot behind him a try to don't shoot him. So he will carry the cash even faster.
- Before you enter a convenience store, make an escape plan. Look for LS-Custom's, winding streets or something. If the police is looking for you (if the wanted stars are blinkng), drive in a LS-Custom and go out again (you don't need to change the color), or drive into a winding street and wait. *Edit*: Just found out that your garage / appartment is also a good place to hide. If you have 3*, drive fast into a train tunnel while they're looking for you (blinking *). So the chopper doesn't see you anymore and if you were fast enough, the police cars also don't find you.
  Here I have marked (red rectangle) my two favourite convenience store's:
  [image]
  They're located ad the bottom of the Sandy Shore desert. When you robbed the store, just drive into the LS-Custom (green rectangle). So you loose the police quickly. And Because the LS-Custom is as close to the store's, the police won't be there and won't see you before you're in the building.
- Change the car to make it harder for the police to find you.
- Before a robbery, buy a mask on the LS-Beach. Then put on the mask and do the robbery. Now, if you put off the mask, you'll loose directly 1* if the police don't see you! And if you enter the store later without a mask, he won't recognize you.

I hope I could help you a bit. And just google for other GTA (online) tips, so you may find some other great tips.

*Credit: Map Shortcut made by [GTA 5 Map](http://gta-5-map.com/)*

Comment: This Map-Website is awesome!

Comment: Does the "they recognize your face" from having robbed a store without a mask ever wear off?

Comment: @Random832: Yes! You can try it by yourself or just search the intermet. Many of these numbered blogs wrote about wearing a mask!

Comment: Also, yell at headset will fill up the shopkeeper threaten meter faster. Yell louder. LOL